# Mapreduce MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I am new to MongoDB / mapreduce.

I am trying to create a map function to show the horses who are female AND have been to less than 50 shows.

```
var mapHorse1 = function(){
this.gender;if(this.gender='f'),this.shows;if(this.shows<50)emit(this.gender,this.shows);};
```

The error is in the comma  (after the first "if" statement. Can someone please assist? The syntax is clearly wrong.

I have tried the following:

```
var mapHorse1 = function(){
this.gender;if(this.gender='f'),this.shows;if(this.shows<50)emit(this.gender,this.shows);};
```

Comment: When you say "The error is in the comma" why did you not simple try to remove it?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why are you using mapreduce here? A `find()` query would probably work

Comment: yes  - i need to use mapreduce as it's an assignment question.